# CodeIgniter 3 URI Paramaters and 404 Pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-3

I have a class named `Collection` with two methods named `Index` and `Cars`.

In it's basic format my controller it looks like this;

```
class Collection extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index(){
        $data = array(
            'title'     =>  'Index Page'
            );
        $this->load->view('template/Header');
        $this->load->view('collection/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/Footer');
    }

    public function cars(){
        $data = array(
            'title'     =>  'Cars Page'
            );
        $this->load->view('template/Header');
        $this->load->view('collection/list_of_cars', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/Footer');
    }
}
```

The URI looks like this;

`example.com/collection/cars`

This does what I want, the `cars` method is processed and the `list_of_cars` view is displayed as usual.

However I notice that if I add another parameter to the URL, e.g

`example.com/collection/cars/something`

In fact, I can add as many additional URI parameters as I like and I still don't get a 404 error.

The page simply reloads - should it not display a 404 error as that page doesn't exist?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: the parameters you given is treated as arguments for the method you are accessing, means if you given like this `example.com/collection/cars/something` you can access this parameter in your `cars` method like this `public function cars($param){ echo $param;}`

Comment: Not sure why you feel this should be a 404 as the argument(s) are ignored and the controller/method does what it should. But if a 404 is what you want @pradeep has given you a good answer.

Comment: If I visit the URI `example.com/collection/cars/something/blah/blah` should I not see a 404 page as the URI doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your URI contains more than two segments they will be passed to your method as parameters.

The segment(s) you given is/are treated as arguments for the method you are accessing, means if you given like this

```
example.com/collection/cars/something
```

you can access this parameter in your cars method like this

```
public function cars($param)
{ 
   echo $param;
}
```

and if you given like this

```
example.com/collection/cars/something/testing
```

you can access this parameter in your cars method like this

```
public function cars($param,$param2)
{ 
   echo $param;
   echo $param2;
}
```

**Update** :

If you want some check condition based on segments  use `$this->uri->segment()` in your method , do like this :

```
if ($this->uri->segment(3) === FALSE)
{
    /*this is your error page*/
     $this->load->view('error-page');
}
else
{
        $arg = $this->uri->segment(3);
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

An approach that is similar can be structured as follows. If there are more than two segments (i.e. a controller + a method) then arguments are present so force a 404.

```
if ($this->uri->total_segments() > 2)
{
     show_404(); //shows 404 page, logs the error, and ends execution
}
```

Read about `show_404()` [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. I still don't see what I need to do in order to get a 404 page? Basically, I *want* to see a 404 page if there are any additional URI paramaters after `/cars/`.

Comment: i have updated my answer see in the last update part for condition based on segments